# How to notify user when iBeacon range is "Immediate" or "near"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

Users will only get notified when they are close enough to the beacon, since then *didEnterRegion* dose not work properly. 
My code is like this:

```
if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]] && ([beaconRegionInStringFormat isEqualToString:@"Immediate"] || [beaconRegionInStringFormat isEqualToString:@"Near"]))
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.alertBody = @"Please open the application";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
}
```

But the notification will keep sending to users. How can I only get notified once?

Comment: Is this code in a didRangeBeacons:InRegion: callback?  What is the code that calculates beaconRegionInStringFormat?

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Adding a flag to your controller

Interface:

`@property (nonatomic) BOOL userNotified;`

Implementation:

```
if (!self.userNotified && [region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]] && ([beaconRegionInStringFormat isEqualToString:@"Immediate"] || [beaconRegionInStringFormat isEqualToString:@"Near"]))
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.alertBody = @"Please open the application";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
    self.userNotified = YES;
}
```

---

### 2. Using the GCD (Grand Central Dispatch)

Using this method the code will be executed only once per app launch.

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once (&onceToken, ^{
    if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]] && ([beaconRegionInStringFormat isEqualToString:@"Immediate"] || [beaconRegionInStringFormat isEqualToString:@"Near"]))
    {
        UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.alertBody = @"Please open the application";
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
    }
});
```